# How to set Laravel 8 language switching configuration?

Tags: php, laravel

I read the Laravel 8 localization documentation and did everything accordingly. I have 2 folders in the lang folder and I changed their language. But this code doesn't work. Can you explain this?

```
@lang('auth.password')
```

Inside this html blade page.

```
Route::get('/change-language/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    if (!in_array($locale, ['en', 'tr'])) {        
        abort(404);
    }

    App::setLocale($locale);

    return redirect()->back();
});
```

Inside this route/web.php

```
<a href="{{ url('change-language/en') }}">English</a>
```

Inside this blade page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about storing local in a session

```
Route::get('/change-language/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    if (!in_array($locale, ['en', 'tr'])) {        
        abort(404);
    }

    App::setLocale($locale);
    // Session
    session()->put('locale', $locale);

    return redirect()->back();
});
```

create a middlware and update its handle method
`php artisan make: middleware Localization`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if (session()->has('locale')) {
            App::setlocale(session()->get('locale'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

then add the new middlware to your  kernel.php under the middlewareGroups array.

```
[
...
\App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class,
]
```

Comment: Yes that worked! But why doesn't the documentation mention them either?